# List too long for `ls` command, CSH

Tags: csh, ls

I want to get a list of all my files of `ofl` type in several directories. I used the fallowing command:

```
ls RESULTS/*/quakesim/iecrud/quake/fgb/stflt/*.ofl
```

but I got a message: `/bin/ls: Argument list too long.` There are a little more than 1600 such files. Is there a way to still get the list of files?

**EDIT:**

I need the paths to the files and not just how many are there the `wc` was as a try to see how many files I have without "polluting" my screen with 1600+ paths.

Comment: Please don't write answers or comments saying I shouldn't use `csh`.

Comment: *This* instance is actually not csh's fault.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php) instead of `ls`.

Example: (assuming your current working directory is the parent of RESULTS)

`find . -name "RESULTS/*/quakesim/iecrud/quake/fgb/stflt/*.ofl" -print`

Second option:

`find . -print | egrep '.ofl$'`

Answer (score 1):

This might be dirty but it works for my needs and within my competency. I don't think it performs very quickly but it allowed me to get on with my day.

```
ls | grep jpg | <something>
```

I was getting a 90,000 long list of jpgs and piping them to avconv to generate a timelapse.

I was previously using ls *.jpg| avconv before I ran into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a quick bash script that iterates through different letters from a to z for one of your two stars, then, for each results, you add the result from wc to the current total for each itteration and you return the result.

You could also see if it would work just using:

```
[a-m]*
[o-z]*
```

on just two different commands. Might be simplier, although I do not know the limit of number of arguments.